# Use Spacewalk externally

Tags: centos, fedora, vps, spacewalk

Is it possible to control vps'es (which reside in an external network)with Spacewalk or can you only control local servers?

Answer (score 1):

You can control any computer, which has routing path from the computer to Spacewalk server.

There does not need to be routing path from Spacewalk server to client. E.g., the client can have private IP, but as long as it can reach the Spacewalk server it is ok.